# Hide Div in ListView if database value is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, hidden

I have a ListView that displays different types of catalogs per item. I would like to hide the catalog div if the value is NULL for "pdflabel", "pdftechlabel", "pdfecolabel", etc...

I have done quite a bit of searching, but my limited knowledge is preventing me from being able to connect all of the dots to make this function as anticipated. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="catalog">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListViewCatalogs" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlCatalogs" OnItemDataBound="ListViewCatalogs_ItemDataBound">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="pdfcatalogs" runat="server">
                <div id="brochure" class="pdfcat" runat="server" >
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("catlinkpath", "Catalogs/{0}.pdf") %>' title='<%# Eval("pdfname") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pdficon") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="catnameLabel" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pdflabel", "{0} Brochure") %>' />
                </div><!--end brochure-->

                <div id="techbrochure" class="pdfcat" runat="server">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("techlinkpath", "Catalogs/{0}.pdf") %>' title='<%# Eval("pdftechname") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pdftechicon") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="technameLabel" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pdftechlabel") %>' />
                </div><!--end techbrochure-->

                <div id="ecobrochure" class="pdfcat" runat="server" >
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ecolinkpath", "Catalogs/{0}.pdf") %>' title='<%# Eval("pdfeconame") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pdfecoicon") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="econameLabel" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pdfecolabel") %>' />
                </div><!--end ecobrochure-->

                <div id="sdsbrochure" class="pdfcat" runat="server" >
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("sdslinkpath", "Catalogs/{0}.pdf") %>' title='<%# Eval("pdfeconame") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pdfsdsicon") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="sdsnameLabel" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pdfsdslabel") %>' />
                </div><!--end sdsbrochure-->

                <div id="otherbrochure" class="pdfcat" runat="server" >
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("otherlinkpath", "Catalogs/{0}.pdf") %>' title='<%# Eval("pdfothername") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pdfothericon") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="othernameLabel" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pdfotherlabel") %>' />
                </div><!--end otherbrochure-->
            </div><!--end pdfcatalogs-->
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style=""><span id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></span></div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div><!--end catalog-->
```

I've added the following (with changes for a ListView instead of a GridView) based on the original and updated answers from Albert D. Kallal.

```
        private void AcceptData(string connectionString)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            string strSQL;
            strSQL = "SELECT pdflabel, pdftechlabel, pdfecolabel, pdfsdslabel, pdfotherlabel from tblcatalogs";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(connectionString)))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                ListViewCatalogs.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
                ListViewCatalogs.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ListViewCatalogs_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.GetType() == typeof(ListViewDataItem))
        {
            Label lTech = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("technameLabel");
            if (lTech.Text == "testing123")
            {
                HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("techbrochure");
                MyDiv.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it is still not hiding the div. I would like the div to be actually "display:none" so that it doesn't take up space in the page. My current issue is that I still have a space for the empty div.

I've found some inline options, but this doesn't work for me either.

```
<div id="techbrochure" class="pdfcat" runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("pdftechname") == null ? true:false %>'>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("techlinkpath", "Catalogs/{0}.pdf") %>' title='<%# Eval("pdftechname") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pdftechicon") %>' />
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="technameLabel" CssClass="pdflinks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pdftechlabel") %>' />
</div><!--end techbrochure-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question!

How you do this for a gridview, listview, formview, and just about "any" repeater object in asp.net? They all work near identical.

thus the general approach is to build everything as you have, and there is one VERY handy and nice event that fires for each row of these so called "repeaters". that is called the RowDataBound event.

It fires for every row during the data bind process, and lets you put nice little routines that do things (like your question) with great ease. So this event fires, and lets you get your grubby hands on the row after it been filled with data, but BEFORE the final rendering process. (and as noted, you learn this for listview, then a near identical approach works for all of the other data bound controls - (they work near all the same in terms of the given event model).

Now one more issue. I suppose we could use sql to check for null values and NOT return the data in the first place - right? (just wanting to suggest that - since it looks like the pdfcatalogs is the whole row (yes?). So we in theory could either change the sql to prevent this.

And even say once we pull that datatable, we could THEN filter the data to not include those rows. However, so far it not clear if we hiding the whole row based on this, or just SOME content on that row? So don't rule out using a filter - they are VERY easy to use and thus you prevent the data rows from being part of the datatalbe in the first place.

So, in most cases, for hiding such rows, then I will simply not include the rows in the first place. However, we often still need/want conditional formatting. (so if you wanted to say add/have/change the color of some row column based on its value, then what we are about to do will and can work very well.

First, you can take a quick gander at this recent post of mine - it was a gridivew, but as I pointed out a identical approach will work for listview:

[How to Highlight Cells with a certain value from the DB in a GridView in ASP .NET using VB Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66287212/how-to-highlight-cells-with-a-certain-value-from-the-db-in-a-gridview-in-asp-ne/66288022#66288022)

In above, I wanted to color some values in the row. In this case, well we just going to hide some - but the approach is identical in execution.

So, in our RowDataBound event, we simple say check catnamelabel, and then hide the div

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // this is a data row!

    Label catlbel = e.Row.FindControl("catnameLabel");
    if (catlbel.Text == "")
    {
        HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = e.Row.FindControl("pdfcatalogs");
        MyDiv.Style("Display") = "none";
    }
}
```

So you can add as many more tests as you with. And nulls will become "" in a label

***Edit: -----------------------***

Here is a example using list view.

First, the markup - we have some standard columns - and NOTE the div I placed around the LAST two columns.

so, we have this:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" style="width:700px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>

                <div id="ProvinceAndComments" runat="server">

                    <td><asp:Label ID="ProvinceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>

                </div>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">ID</th>
                    <th runat="server" width="140px">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                    <th runat="server">Province</th>
                    <th runat="server">Description</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

(I even let the wizard create the rows for me - after all this is just a Q+A, so not a lot of work.

Ok, now in our on-load event, we load up the listview with this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack == false)
   {
    string strSQL;
    strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName, FirstName, City, Province, Description from tblHotels";

    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        ListView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
   }
}
```

Ok, above is a wee few lines of code. We now get/see this:

[image]

Now, note our "div" in above markup. This one:

```
<div id="ProvinceAndComments" runat="server">

   <td><asp:Label ID="ProvinceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>' /></td>
   <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>

</div>
```

Ok, so lets "hide" this div say if Province = "AB".

So, in the item bound event. (dispay the property sheet - just double click on that event - you jumped to the code editor.

So, we now have this wee bit of code:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.GetType == typeof(ListViewDataItem))
    {
       Label lProvince = e.Item.FindControl("ProvinceLabel");
       if (lProvince.Text == "AB")
          {
          HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = e.Item.FindControl("ProvinceAndComments");
          MyDiv.Visible = false;
          }
    }
}
```

Ok, so we just "hide" that div. It surrounds the last two columns. So, now run this code, and you get this:

[image]

As noted, I could hide a whole row based on whatever criteria I want, but the above "div" was surrounding the last two columns. Do note that you have to give it a "ID" and of course use runat="server" for code behind to see + use such controls. Now I used a div "around" the columns AND controls.
I suppose you could just pluck out the controls by name, and hide them that way, but I depends on how much you looking to hide or show.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I've updated my original question. It's still giving me a blank space where the empty div is.

Comment: Hum, but does the div content hide? As I noted in my post, if the full row is not to be displayed, then it less code to filter it out at the data level. Also, it could be the class for that div - perhaps try setting that in the row bind code. Quite sure hiding the div should hide the row - it just depends where the div winds up here.

Comment: You could also hide the whole row like this: e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "display:none"; So you could hide the whole row by trying this idea in the row data bind event

Comment: To hide the full row, this works for me:        e.Row.Style("Display") = "none" ----- this also works:  e.Row.Visible = false;   --- this would suggest that the div we using can be dumped.

Comment: I think my disconnect is that I'm using a ListView and not a GridView. I would like to hide the entire div if the "...nameLabel" field is NULL. In the live page source, I see this: 
`
<div id="techbrochure" class="pdfcat">
     <a id="ListView6_HyperLink6_0" class="pdflinks" title="" target="_blank"></a>
     <br>
     <span id="ListView6_Label11_0" class="pdflinks"></span>
</div>
`

Comment: Is the div the whole row, or just parts in the row? (but, gridview or listview really don't make a lot of difference here). I'll look at your "div" and a listview a bit closer.  I not 100% sure if that div is allowed like that anyway - but I'll look closer at the markup. In my last comments, I assumed that you just want to hide the whole row. it not clear now if this is to hide some columns, or part of what makes up a given row. But, I see no problem with either goal. I mean a quick look at the posted markup? It sure looks like hiding that one div would in fact hide the whole row.

Comment: Ok, see my edit + example I posted. As noted, the event model and how this works for any of the repeater objects is much the same. Once you learn one, then you can do the same for near anything. So, say about 5 mins from this post- I'll add a listview example.

Comment: You have the patience of a saint, kind Sir. I've updated my code in the question to reflect your edits. I had to make a few adjustments to correct errors, but I must have botched that, as it's still not hiding the div.

Updates to your suggestions include moving the connectionString bit into a private void to fix a "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized" error. I added () after ExecuteReader. In the ItemDataBound event I added () after e.Item.GetType and  needed to implicitly "define(?)" (Label) and (HtmlGenericControl). Those fixes(?) got rid of my red squigglies,

Comment: Funny how truckloads of examples create a connect object, then data reader object, and even var to hold sql. The sqlCommand object has all 3 built in! However not really important since we assume from day 1 the grid (or listview) is displaying data (so without data row event code, listview does display data, right?). "Basic" concept of using "data bound" row event to conditional show/hide or format control colors etc. in that event is the meat and potatoes of this example. As such this concept is quite separate from the code to load the grid in the first place. We assumed a working listview.

Comment: I took a bit of a break from this. Came back to it today, verified the listview was working, and implemented all of your suggestions. Now I'm getting the error: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Comment: How can the listview work when the conneciton string does not? A working connection is the most basic 101 starting point here. You can go Project->"Your web app name shows here"->Properties. From that you can select Settings. And you add as many settings as you need/want/have/had . And of course that includes your connection string. We assume you had/have  a working connection from day one else your listview would have never worked. I used My.Settings.Test3, but you of course use whatever you been using and setup in place of "Test3"